# Connecting Haskell to Postgres: Module not found

Tags: postgresql, haskell

I want to access a Postgres database via a Haskell function. I found this [tutorial](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.0.0/candidate/docs/Database-PostgreSQL-Simple.html#g:8), however, whenever I try to apply this code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Database.PostgreSQL.Simple

hello :: IO Int
hello = do
  conn <- connectPostgreSQL ""
  [Only i] <- query_ conn "select 2 + 2"
  return i
```

it tells me "Could not find module 'Database.PostreSQL.Simple'. 
Why does this happen and how do I fix it?

Thanks for your answers beforehand.

Comment: Did you install the relevant package using `cabal install ...` ?

Comment: Thank you, that was it. However, now I have a problem with installing it. When I use "cabal install [URL]" it complains about the data not being in tar format. Also, I'm not sure, whether to use https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.0.0 or https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.0.0/src/. I thought the latter one would be in tar format.

Comment: @marakatrin I would suggest you to use cabal sandbox. If you are just starting out and want a more intuitive experience, I would recommend using Stack.

Comment: I recommend stack as well. You should be able to use `cabal install PACKAGE_NAME` rather than specifying the url I believe. But probably the correct url would be `https://hackage.haskell.org/package/postgresql-simple-0.5.0.0/postgresql-simple-0.5.0.0.tar.gz` in this case.

Comment: I'm starting to get really desperate now. However I try to install  the package, I always get some error. When I try cabal install postgressql-simple, I get "cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
postgresql-libpq-0.9.3.1 failed during the configure step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
postgresql-simple-0.5.3.0 depends on postgresql-libpq-0.9.3.1 which failed to
install." . When I try using Stack, it tells me I have no space left.

Comment: @marakatrin I suggest you seek more interactive help, such as on irc.freenode.net #haskell.  If you are out of space then that's obviously a problem you'll have to take care of.  Notice postgresql-libpq requires postgres system packages to be installed, such as `postgresql-server-dev-9.5` on Ubuntu.